# md-circular-progress is not animating

Tags: angularjs, animation, angular-material

I'm using angular material design circular progress, but it is not animating

Angular module declaration

```
var app = angular.module('abc', ['ngRoute', 'ngProgress', 'ngAnimate', 'ngAria', 'ngMaterial']);
```

usage of md circular progress

```
<md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circular>
```

but it is not animating, I have also included all files into my html and using v 1.3.0

when I inspected the element I found that

```
animation: sporadic-rotate 5.25s cubic-bezier(.35,0,.25,1) infinite;
```

is not applied on md-inner element.

Can you tell me that what is wrong here.

angular material design version 0.10.0

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error and it was caused by a version mismatch between the Angular Material CSS and the Angular Material JS file.

Example (BAD):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.4/angular-material.min.css">
<script data-require="angular-material@0.11.4" data-semver="0.11.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Notice that the versions are different on the require lines.  I had forgotten to update the JS when I updated the CSS require.

Fixed:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Note the matching versions.

Reference for setting up Angular Material
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started